# Concurrent Net::HTTP.get to same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, http, centos

As part of my Ruby on Rails application, I need to perform several (a few dozen) web requests to a foreign web server -- all on the same domain. I am aware of the two requests per domain throttle on Windows and know how to adjust that, but this application is running on CentOS and I was not expecting to run into this same issue, but I seem to be.

Does this same-domain-throttling exist on *nix? If so, how can I adjust it?

Answer (score 1):

I think its not a OS issue but a Protocol issue.

**Http 1.1 allows only 2 simulataneous requests to a hostname.**

**Note:** http://one.yourdomain.com, http://two.yourdomain.com are considered different hostnames

HTH

Comment: sez who and where? I've regularly broken that rule on Windows.

Comment: from RFC2616, 8.1.4 Practical Considerations "... A single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy. ..." - not a single-user client, doesn't say MUST - but +1 for you to recall that it was part of the spec.

Comment: Its a specification, so I guess both windows and *nix follow it. Setting up a proxy means your are setting up another client, but you probably have restriction of two from that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works better with other libraries like Typhoeus : [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) or, if you're usning EventMachine : [EM-Http-Request](http://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/tree/master) they both allow multi-request and you should be able to send more than 2 to the same domain (at least it does with Ubuntu)